# Migrating from docker-compose v2 to v3

Tags: docker

I have a little problem migrating to docker-compose v3. Currently I have nginx container with php-fpm that share the same volumes. My setup looks like this

```
nginx:
    build:
        context: ./nginx
    depends_on: 
        - php-fpm
        - mariadb
    volumes_from: 
        - php-fpm
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    networks: 
        - lemp-network

php-fpm:
    build:
        context: ./php-fpm       
    volumes: 
        - ..:/var/www/hosts
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
        - lemp-network
```

If I have to create shared volume with both of this containers how can I do this in version 3?